# access azure key vault from azure web app where ip changes often bc of CI/CD

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-webapps

I have a docker container that accesses azure key vault. this works when I run it locally.

I set up an azure web app to host my container, and it cannot access the key vault

```
  Forbidden (HTTP 403). Failed to complete operation. Message:
Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.
Client address: 51.142.174.224 Caller:
```

I followed the suggestion from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIXbyInGXd8 and
I went to the web app in the portal to set status to on

[image]

Created an access policy

[image]

and then receive the same error with a different ip

```
  Forbidden (HTTP 403). Failed to complete operation. Message:
Client address is not authorized and caller is not a trusted service.
Client address: 4.234.201.129 Caller:
```

My web app ip address would change every time an update were made, so are there any suggestions how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on your exact use case and what you want to achieve with your tests, but you could consider using a test double instead of the real Azure Key Vault while running your app locally or on CI.

If you are interested please feel free to check out [Lowkey Vault](https://github.com/nagyesta/lowkey-vault).

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by setting up a virtual network,

[image]

and then whitelisting it in the keyvault access rights

[image]

Comment: Answer doesn't explain the process followed while setting up Virtual Network. Can you try to explain this piece or point to a ref, link